# Haskell Recursion and Type Error

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

I'm teaching myself Haskell and the best way to learn any programming language is to use it.  My current "exercise" is an implementation of take.  The pseudo-code is:

```
take(0, list) = [] --empty list
take(n, list) = const(head(list), take(n-1, tail(list))
```

What I've worked out in Haskell is:

```
myTake :: (Num a) => a -> [b] -> [b]
myTake 0 l = []
myTake n (l:ls) = l :  myTake n-1 ls
```

This doesn't compile when I load the file in GHCi.  This is the error message I get:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[b]'
       against inferred type `[b1] -> [b1]'
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `myTake n - 1 ls'
In the expression: l : myTake n - 1 ls
In the definition of `myTake':
    myTake n (l : ls) = l : myTake n - 1 ls
```

My current Haskell resource is "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" and I've read the section on types several times trying to figure this out.  Google has been unusually unhelpful too.  I think that I don't entirely understand typing yet.  Can anyone explain what's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myTake n - 1 ls
```

is parsed like

```
(myTake n) - (1 ls)
```

because function application binds higher than any infix operator. Parenthesize it:

```
myTake (n - 1) ls
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.  I'm glad it was just something simple like that.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always parenthesize expression which are an argument to a prefix function, if they are more than just a variable name.

Comment: Note this is why `x : f y` works, because the function application `f y` binds more tightly than `:`, so it's as if you had parenthesized `x : (f y)`

Comment: Actually the error message is this way because `:` binds more tightly than `-`, so it's parsed as `(l : (myTake n)) - (1 ls)`. This is why it complains that the second argument of `:` is a function - myTake is only partially applied.